# Pattern and Structure Mathematics Awareness Program (pasmap)

Tags: reference-books, resource-request, book

I am looking for a book or any resources related to this book. It is called Pattern and Structure Mathematics Awareness Program (there is a book one and book two).

I have tried to order it but it is out of stock in the three places that I ordered from.

Can anyone shed light on where I can get this from?

Thanks and have a good one!

Comment: It doesn't look promising. I look for books by using bookfinder.com. It only shows one copy of each, at ridiculous price. https://www.bookfinder.com/search/?full=on&ac=sl&st=sl&ref=bf_s2_a1_t1_1&qi=dS72h12cPAGMxI2RNJlkZQw7LqU_1497963026_1:1:2

Answer (score 2):

I would borrow it from a library. Use InterLibrary Loan (ILL) if in the US.  This means you can get the volumes from the distant library sent to yours.

https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=Pattern+and+Structure+Mathematics+Awareness+Program&qt=owc_search

Comment: Thank you I will try this